# How to read JSON from a REST URL and load to an Array

Tags: c#, json

I have a rest service URL like:

```
http://domain.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/appData?f=json&pretty=true
```

which the JSON looks like

```
{"currentVersion" : 10.05, 
  "folders" : [], 
  "services" : [
    {"name" : "appData/Drainage", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Parks", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Planning", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/QNet", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Sanitary", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Street_Lights", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Survey", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Transportation", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Water", "type" : "MapServer"}
  ]
}
```

How can set a request to the service in C# and load all names after `appData/` to an array called `servicesList` ?

Comment: Can you share the code that you've tried so far? Are you using `HttpClient` to make the connection or are you using a library like `EasyHttp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following unit test demonstrates

> How can set a request to the service in C# and load all names after `appData/` to an array called `servicesList` ?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest3 {
    public async Task GetServicesList() {
        var url = "http://domain.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/appData?f=json";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(json);
        var servicesList = model.services.Select(s => s.name.Replace("appData/", "")).ToArray();
    }

    public class Service {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServiceResponse {
        public double currentVersion { get; set; }
        public IList<object> folders { get; set; }
        public IList<Service> services { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NKosi, but I am getting error on `var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ServiceResponse>();`  VS complains the 'HtttpContent' does not cotain a defination for 'ReadAsAsync' and no extension method ....

Comment: It's an extension method. You are probably missing a library. I'll update to use Json.Net

Comment: It is an extension method found in `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, v5.2.3.0`. It basically replaces the two lines I updated in the answer.

Comment: Do I need to import JSON dll here? because I am getting error on `JsonConvert` now

Comment: yes check NuGet for Json.Net. I am surprised it is not already referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lots Nkosi,

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any classes, just one string of code will extract from a json string the data you neeed

```
//.... http request code that will  be like the one from @Nkosi answer

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

string[] services = JObject.Parse(json)["services"]
                    .Select(x => ((string)x["name"]).Substring("appData/".Length))))
                    .ToArray();
```